# Как пишется и произносится дата — с такого-то по такой-то годов??

Tags: грамотная-речь

1836-1838 годов (Причина восстания И.Тайманулы 1836-1838 годов ...)

Answer (score 1):

Так, как у Вас указано. Пропущен 1837 год, речь идёт о трёх годах:

*Причина восстания И.Тайманулы тысяча восемьсот тридцать шестого — тысяча восемьсот тридцать восьмого годов...*

Это продолжительность восстания.

(Цифрами — тире без отбивок: 1836—1838 годов.)

Было по-иному:

*...восстание длилось с тысяча восемьсот тридцать шестого* (года) *по тысяча восемьсот тридцать восьмой год...*

Comment: Саша, спасибо, отточия щас приклеим, а тире что? чтобы ответ дать, надо скопиовать полиграфическое тире?

Comment: Не, красота — страшная сила, кто б спорил, но мне сподручней миновать вопрос, чем разводить ея. )))